# How to switch Display between different classes in Java ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am developing a Java ME program. The different forms are located in separate classes. I tried to switch display between main `MIDlet` and a class and succeeded. How to do the same between two classes? I am just a beginner in Java ME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use following code for the same,

- First display a static Display variable in Midlet

  ```
  private static Display display;
  ```
- Now initialize the dislplay variable in class Constructor

  ```
  public MyMidlet() {
       display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  }
  ```
- Now declare a getDisplay() method in Midlet class

  ```
  public static Display getDisplay () {
       return display;
  }
  ```

Now you can use this getDisplay() method to get the current Display's object and then set any class's form

```
MyMidlet.getDisplay().setCurrent(form);
```

Comment: I am getting a nullopinter exception. Can you please elaborate the getDisplay() method.

Comment: @SabinJose, sorry, it was mistake from my side, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simplification is:

```
  Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(screen);
```

Where **screen** is an instance of LCDUI (Form, Alert...) or intance of Canvas object. 
The **this** is an instance of the MIDlet